# Yes/No button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dry, togglebutton

I have a code for a simple yes/no button selection which will auto fill an input value to be used in a form. My question is how to simplify the jquery part of code? as I have to add more yes/no question.

```js
$('#y01').click(function() {
  $('#y01').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#n01').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#ans01').val('Yes');
});

$('#n01').click(function() {
  $('#y01').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#n01').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#ans01').val('No');
});

$('#y02').click(function() {
  $('#y02').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#n02').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#ans02').val('Yes');
});

$('#n02').click(function() {
  $('#y02').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#n02').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#ans02').val('No');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans01" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y01" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n01" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans02" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y02" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n02" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DOM navigation methods to refer to the button that you click on and the siblings in the same group.

Give the hidden answer field a class so you can refer to it similarly.

```js
$(".button1").click(function() {
  var otherButton = this.value == "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes";
  $(this).css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $(this).siblings(`.button1[value=${otherButton}]`).css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $(this).siblings(".answer").val(this.value);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans01" class="answer" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y01" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n01" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans02" class="answer" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y02" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n02" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Comment: ahh that's snazzy

Answer (score 1):

A simple helper function should work:

```
function assignYesNoStyle(yesId, noId, ansId) {
    $(yesId).click(function() {
        $(yesId).css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
        $(noId).css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
        $(ansId).val('Yes');
    });

    $(noId).click(function() {
        $(yesId).css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
        $(noId).css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
        $(ansId).val('No');
    });
}
```

And then where your script inits, just say:

```
assignYesNoStyle('#y01', '#n01', '#ans01');
assignYesNoStyle('#y02', '#n02', '#ans02');
```

Copy/paste as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Treated them as two separate concerns: first, to toggle the sibling button, and second, to set the hidden element's value.
YMMV

```js
$('td input[type="button"]').click(function() {
  // get the clicked element.
  let clickedBtn = $(this);
  // set its css...
  clickedBtn.css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'})
  // find its sibling button(s)...
  .siblings('[type="button"]')
  // and set THEIR css
  .css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
});

$("[value='No'], [value='Yes']").click(function(){
  let clickedBtn = $(this);
  clickedBtn.siblings('[hidden]').val(clickedBtn.val() );
  console.log(clickedBtn.val() );
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans01" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y01" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n01" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans02" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y02" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n02" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems to much for just pair of buttons, so you can use the event delegation to take your approach to the next level, so basically you should delegate the event click for specific classes and use the attributes for each node (buttons)

so imagine you have

```
<button class="delegated-node" value="yes">Yes</button>
<button class="delegated-node" value="no">No</button>
```

then you should have your JS like

```
$('table').on('click', '.delegated-node', function(event) {
   const target = event.target;
   const currentValue = $(this).val();
   const targetHiddenInput = $(this).data('target-input');
   var targetInput = $('#'+targetHiddenInput);
   // if input doesn't exist yet
   if (!targetInput.length) {
     $('table').append($('<input id="'+ targetHiddenInput +'" type="hidden" />'));
     targetInput = $('#'+targetHiddenInput)
   }
   targetInput.val(currentValue);
});
```

```js
var tableId = "tableResponse";
$('#'+tableId).on('click', '.delegated-node', function(event) {
   const target = event.target;
   const currentValue = $(this).val();
   const targetHiddenInput = $(this).data('target-input');
   var targetInput = $('#'+targetHiddenInput);
   // if input doesn't exist yet
   if (!targetInput.length) {
     $('table').append($('<input id="'+ targetHiddenInput +'" type="hidden" />'));
     targetInput = $('#'+targetHiddenInput)
   }
   targetInput.val(currentValue);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableResponse">

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" data-target-input="ans1" class="button button1 delegated-node" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" data-target-input="ans1" class="button button1 delegated-node" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" data-target-input="ans2" class="button button1 delegated-node" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" data-target-input="ans2" class="button button1 delegated-node" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #3?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" data-target-input="ans3" class="button button1 delegated-node" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" data-target-input="ans3" class="button button1 delegated-node" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

All you need is to duplicate the buttons code and change the `target-input` data information to the name for the next hidden input that keep the answers.

So the input will be created as the user click for each pair of button, check this into your console

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery you could do:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach((tr, i) => {
  const buttons = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll(".button"))
  const hidden = tr.querySelector(".hidden")
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      const val = evt.target.value
      console.log(`Answer ${i+1}: ${val}`)
      hidden.value = val
      buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('active'))
      evt.target.classList.toggle('active')
    })
  })
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.active {
  background: #0080FF;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans01" class="hidden" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y01" class="button yes button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n01" class="button no button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans02" class="hidden" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y02" class="button yes button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n02" class="button no button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead of `.css()`. Also do not repeat code. You are using #id which forces you to make one-off functions. jQuery is flexible and using classes is the best course of action 99.9% of the time. In order to reference the button that was clicked by user use `this` keyword or `event.target` Event property. BTW this:

> *"Do you have any question #1?"*

Is not only wrong it is grammatically painful.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  const cell = $(this).parent('td');
  if ($(this).is('.y')) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    cell.find('.answer').val($(this).val());
    cell.find('.n').removeClass('active');
  } else if ($(this).is('.n')) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    cell.find('.answer').val($(this).val());
    cell.find('.y').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  console.log(cell.find('.answer').val());
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
  background: transparent;
}

.active {
  background: #0080FF;
  color: white;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.question::after {
  content: ' #'attr(data-id)'?'
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td class='question' data-id='1'>
      Do you have any questions
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="answer" name='answer' type="hidden">
      <input class="button y" type="button" value="Yes">
      <input class="button n" type="button" value="No">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='question' data-id='2'>
      Do you have any questions
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="answer" name='answer' type="hidden">
      <input class="button y" type="button" value="Yes">
      <input class="button n" type="button" value="No">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='question' data-id='3'>
      Do you have any questions
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="answer" name='answer' type="hidden">
      <input class="button y" type="button" value="Yes">
      <input class="button n" type="button" value="No">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='question' data-id='4'>
      Do you have any questions
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="answer" name='answer' type="hidden">
      <input class="button y" type="button" value="Yes">
      <input class="button n" type="button" value="No">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='question' data-id='5'>
      Do you have any questions
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="answer" name='answer' type="hidden">
      <input class="button y" type="button" value="Yes">
      <input class="button n" type="button" value="No">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='question' data-id='6'>
      Do you have any questions
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="answer" name='answer' type="hidden">
      <input class="button y" type="button" value="Yes">
      <input class="button n" type="button" value="No">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick i hope it helps.

```js
$('input[type="button"]').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr('id').slice(0, 1) == 'y') {
      $(this).closest('td').find($('input[type="button"]')).css({
        'background': 'transparent',
        'color': '#808080'
      });
      $(this).css({
        'background': '#0080FF',
        'color': 'white'
      });
      $(this).closest('td').find($('input[type="text"]')).attr('value', 'Yes');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('td').find($('input[type="button"]')).css({
        'background': 'transparent',
        'color': '#808080'
      });
      $(this).css({
        'background': '#0080FF',
        'color': 'white'
      });
      $(this).closest('td').find($('input[type="text"]')).attr('value', 'No');
    }
  });
});
/*
$('input[type="text"]')
$('#y01').click(function() {
  $('#y01').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#n01').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#ans01').val('Yes');
});

$('#n01').click(function() {
  $('#y01').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#n01').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#ans01').val('No');
});

$('#y02').click(function() {
  $('#y02').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#n02').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#ans02').val('Yes');
});

$('#n02').click(function() {
  $('#y02').css({'background':'transparent', 'color':'#808080'});
  $('#n02').css({'background':'#0080FF', 'color':'white'});
  $('#ans02').val('No');
});*/
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans01" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y01" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n01" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans02" hidden/>
      <input type="button" id="y02" class="button button1" value="Yes" />
      <input type="button" id="n02" class="button button1" value="No" />
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drop jquery/javascript here all together and just use radio buttons with CSS.

With this you no longer really need the hidden field as you can retrieve the value of the selected radio button both server and client side.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: fff;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: 100px;
}

.button1 {
  color: #808080;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:visited {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.hidden {display:none;}

/*Change the color of our "buttons"*/
[type=radio]:checked + .button1 {
 background-color: #0080FF;
 color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #1?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans01" hidden/>
      <input type="radio" id="ans01_yes" value="Yes" name="ans01" class="hidden"><label class="button button1" for="ans01_yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="ans01_no" value="No" name="ans01" class="hidden"><label class="button button1" for="ans01_no">No</label>
      
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
      Do you have any question #2?
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="ans02" hidden/>
      <input type="radio" id="ans02_yes" value="Yes" name="ans02" class="hidden"><label class="button button1" for="ans02_yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="ans02_no" value="No" name="ans02" class="hidden"><label class="button button1" for="ans02_no">No</label>
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>
```

On a side note, keep the `table` tag for tabular data. There are **many** better ways to layout elements using CSS that avoids the `table` tag all together.